# Azure Portal - ResourceGroup linked to App Service doesnt work

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-resource-group

I am new here and in MS Azure as well so sorry in advance for any misunderstanding.

I have a question related to the Azure Portal and Resource Group.

I have successfully built an image, created a container where the image has been pushed and no I have ResourceGroup That I can see available on the Azure Portal.
I also successfully start App Service and I can see the attribut ResourceGroup on the AppService heading right to my correctly build on the Azure Portal.

And here is the issue...

On the AppService, there is provided URL, where your cloud app is running and I cant see anything on the URL, just bluescreen which telling me to deploy the code. BUT, the resourceGroup with the code has been linked to the App Service.

I am so confused by Azure Portal Gui... and maybe I missed some tutorial or hint on the net. Does anybody has any experiences with Azure Cloud and uploading Web App ?

I am using Trial-Account.

BR
Michal.

Answer (score 1):

The "Resource Group" in Azure is a way to organize related resources together. An "App Service Plan", a "Web App", etc are individual Resources. You organize multiple individual resources into Resource Groups by placing resources that are create and/or managed together in the same Resource Group. This is generally done to organize all the resources for a particular workload to be in the same Resource Group.

To publish your application code, you need to publish the code to the App Service Web App. Resource Groups don't host code, they are just for organization. You will deploy your application code and host it within the App Service Web App.

Please refer to the documentation for further explanation on how to deploy your code to App Service, manage it, and host it there:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet